# Solace Queue With Message Selector Without Consumers but Using Solace Gui

Tags: java, producer-consumer, publishing, solace

We are using Solace Pub Sub Version 10.6.2

We have a Java Publisher that will publish to dynamic topic based on message payload. So we have a bunch of headers and will publish to a dynamic queue based on the headers.

For Example we should publish to SOURCE_TYPE/SEC_LEVEL/DESTINATION/

SOURCE_TYPE would be the message type
SEC_LEVEL is who can see these message everyone or is sensitive data included
DESTINATION is where is this message going

So from what my counterpart told me who worked with solace prior is that our java publisher can producer these messages on dynamic topics with no issues. From my research it seems that if we have our vpn configured for DMR that the java publisher can create topics for the message headers as needed. I did a little hackish test but was able to write hello world messages to a topic I created by my java publisher and the solace GUI showed the incoming message rate. I am assuming this will work fine.

Where I get confused is the second part of this task is they want to funnel the data from multiple dynamic topics onto queues. I was specifically told that I could create a queue in the GUI that would not be dynamic. This queue would have multiple subscriptions added to it that would automatically pull in the data published to the topics. I did another test where I created a queue and added a subscription with the dynamic topic name I created in the first test name with no success. I never saw messages come into this queue. I did another test by adding a message subscription to a physical topic that was on a non DMR message vpn that was created months ago on the solace GUI and writing test messages to it. This worked with the message selector and not being DMR.

Am I simply adding the subscription incorrectly or is this message selector(topic_name) added to the solace queue not going to consume messages from a topic for DMR? DO we have to do something different in regards to dynamic topics and queue subscriptions. Ultimately I want to filter based on topic name we create dynamically.

https://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/Selectors.htm

Thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: Can you provide more information about how selectors are being used? Based on your description, the messages that are published to topics that match the subscription added to your queue should be spooled on the queue. It's unclear how selectors come into play in your use case.

Comment: So jsut to give a resolution. I was able to configure this. It turns out that I was ending my subscriptions with a * when I should have been ending with a >. Thanks for the help